# Querying Last Week's data amd this week's data up to today

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am having a problem with making a Oracle Query that sums up everything that occurs during the whole last week and everything during this week. so lets say i have this table

```
DATA DATE
3    2-feb-15    
4    3-feb-15
6    3-feb-15
7    27-jan-2015
5    27-jan-2015
4    25-jan-2015
```

so lets today is feb 5th and the query this week should be 3+4+6 assuming that sunday is feb 1st. The this week's data range should be (feb 2nd - feb 5th) minus sunday.

and the sum for last week should be 7+5+4 no matter what date today is as long as it still last week from Monday to saturday

Another case is, if todays date is feb 2nd, then the sum should be 3.

Please help me, i tried with SYSDATE - (Var) and it doesnt work because it doesnt position the date according to the calendar

thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
trunc(sysdate)
```

I hope its working if its not please give me more detail of your problem

Comment: what an answer :) thaks Karam